# is there a build-in method to convert from Rectangle to RectangleGeometry

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been looking around I can't seem to find a build-in way to do the "conversion", I just need a confirmation before I do it.

Do I have to manually create the **Rect** object based on the **Rectangle** proprieties and pass it in the **RectangleGeometry** constructor?

(I hope there is a build-in way...)

Comment: As far as I know (and as far as I looked through MSDN) there is no conversion.

Answer (score 1):

A `Rectangle` is a `FrameworkElement`/`Visual` that may be displayed in the visual tree and `Rect` is a simple struct, i.e. they aren't similar objects and there is no straightforward conversion: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f5feb8b2-0555-403e-a1f9-967ccf970c7a/how-can-i-transform-rectangle-to-rect-and-vice-versa?forum=winappswithcsharp

So yes, you should manually create the `Rect` object based on the size of the `Rectangle` element.

Answer (score 0):

A Rectangle only has `(Actual)Width` and `(Actual)Height` properties, while (in addition to `Width` and `Height`) a Rect also has `X` and `Y` properties.

You may however directly get a RectangleGeometry from a Rectangle's `RenderedGeometry` property:

```
var rectangleGeometry = rectangle.RenderedGeometry as RectangleGeometry;
```